# create VertexId from VertexProperty

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

I am new to Spark , what I want to do is to create a Graph connecting a `seller` and a `device`, the `device` is a `String` , when I am creating a `Edge` ,I have to give a `VertexId`, how to generate `VertexId` from `VertexProperty` in spark

Comment: You are trying to build a bipartite graph?

Comment: @eliasah, yes, it's a bipartite graph

Comment: Could you provide example input?

Comment: @zero323 isn't it similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/33243012/3415409

Comment: I thought about an it is possible but I think this one is more about adding an ID (`StringIndexer` or `distinct.zipWithIndex.collectAsMap`).  Still it is just a guess.

Comment: @zero323, like I (123, "abc"), (456, "cde")

Comment: @zero323, after checking the document, StringIndexer is exactly the function am looking for , thx